# Clear v-autocomplete items after item selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using the vuetify autocomplete element.Initially when the use focuses on the autocomplete elements no suggestions are shown.  When a user enters text a GET request is made to my server to get the data for the :items prop. When a user selects a item from the suggestions a chip is created and shown. Now when the autocomplete is unfocused and refocused suggests are shown for the old text that was entered. How can I clear the old suggested items. I tried clearing the array used for the items props, I didn't work. Any help?

```
<v-autocomplete
          v-model="friends"
          :disabled="isUpdating"
          :items="people"
          filled
          chips
          color="blue-grey lighten-2"
          label="Select"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="name"
          multiple
        >
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] with what you have tried. Best would be to create a codepen/codesandbox or something similar to play with.

Comment: Have you tried setting the v-model to an empty array?

Comment: use `clearable` prop for clear selected item.